Problot list of lists with differents colors
I am working on some data which are supposed to follow a normal distribution.
I have different sets of samples I'm interested in studying. So the data is stored in a list of lists (each sublist corresponding to a set).
To check the hypothesis of the normal distribution, I want to plot Henry's line (i.e. Quantile Quantile diagram) of the data.
I would like to plot all the data on the same QQ-diagram thanks to the probplot function (statistics package), but I also would like to plot the data from the different sets in different colors to identify them.
I can plot the QQ diagram for all the data by creating a list concatenating all the sample values, but I don't know how to plot the points with different colors corresponding to the sets. I tried to store the slope and intercept given by the probplot function to plot the sets with a for loop but it didn't work either.
Here is what I have done for the moment, and which works but with all the points in the same color (please note that these are fake values, just for the public example that is given here) :
Listes = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11,12,13,14,15]]
Liste_cumulee = np.array([])
for i in range(len(Listes)):
     Liste_cumulee   = np.concatenate(( Liste_cumulee,  Listes[i] ), axis = None)

plt.figure()
probplot(Liste_cumulee, dist="norm", plot=plt)
plt.title("Droite de Henry")
plt.xlabel("Quantiles théoriques")
plt.ylabel("Quantiles observés")
plt.grid()
plt.show()


Here is what I tried with the for-loop but which do not work :
# Ajustement de la droite de Henry aux données concaténées
(_, _), (_, intercept, r) = stats.probplot(Liste_cumulee, dist="norm", plot=None)

# Tracé de la droite de Henry
plt.figure()
plt.title(f"Droite de Henry (r={r:.2f})")
plt.xlabel("Quantiles théoriques")
plt.ylabel("Quantiles observés")
plt.grid()

# Tracé des points pour chaque lot de données avec des couleurs différentes
for i, lot in enumerate(Listes):
    plt.plot(np.sort(lot), stats.norm.ppf(np.linspace(0.01, 0.99, len(lot))), marker='o', linestyle='', label=f'Lot {i+1}', color=plt.cm.tab10(i))

# Affichage du graphique
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Can someone help me with this ? :)
P.S : As you can note english is not my first language, sorry for the eventuals mistakes.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

here is the code. Now for each data set, create points of the same color.
Below the:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Listes = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]

plt.figure()

# Iterate over each sublist
for color, sublist in enumerate(Listes):

    # Iterate over each value in the sublist
    for index, value in enumerate(sublist):

        # Plot a point with a different color
        plt.plot(index + 1, value, color=f'C{color}', marker="o")

# Add title, etc.
plt.title("Droite de Henry")
plt.xlabel("Quantiles théoriques")
plt.ylabel("Quantiles observés")

# Show the plot
plt.show()

Modify the +1 to change values sur l'axe x.
Here the result:

P.S: J'espère avoir bien compris le problème et t'avoir aidé.
